# Delete columns of a matrix that are mostly zero

Tags: python, numpy

In this case, mostly means less than 5 elements are non-zero in a column. Matrix is a 2d ndarray.

Sample data:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,2,1,1],
              [1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,1,0,3,0],
              [1,1,0,3,0],
              [1,1,1,5,3],
              [1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,1,0,1,0],
              [1,1,4,3,0],
              [1,1,0,4,0],
              [1,1,0,5,0],
              [1,1,0,0,0]])
```

Output

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,3],
              [1,1,3],
              [1,1,5],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,1],
              [1,1,3],
              [1,1,4],
              [1,1,5],
              [1,1,0]])
```

Comment: what is the shape of your matrix?

Comment: @Moj, any shape, it's a 2d ndarray. Assume there are more than 5 elements in a column

Comment: Are you expecting to delete more columns than you retain, or the converse?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it depends on the data, but generally I expect to retain the majority of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> a[:, (a != 0).sum(axis=0) >= 5]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

or

```
>>> a[:, np.apply_along_axis(np.count_nonzero, 0, a) >= 5]
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

In the past I've found `np.count_nonzero` to be much faster than the `sum` trick, but here -- probably because of the need to use `np.appyly_along_axis` -- that version is instead much slower, at least for this `a`.  Some other tests showed the same even for larger matrices, but YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've figured it out:

```
np.delete(a, np.nonzero((a==0).sum(axis=0) > 5), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An inefficient version:

```
>>> np.array(zip(*(i for i in zip(*a) if i.count(0) < len(i)/2)))
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 3],
       [1, 1, 4],
       [1, 1, 5],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```